Webscraping NSE Option Data of past 1 year
I'm looking for help to scrape all options data (calls and puts) for any underlying stock or index on the NSE probably for the last 1 year. Does anyone know a reliable resource for this, or can someone guide me through web scraping the NSE's options data? Any pointers or code samples would be greatly appreciated!
Earlier I was using Beautiful soup in Pyhthon, but It didn't work correctly. So I moved to Powershell and started uding Puppeteer with Headless Chrome. Now I am stuck even in Powershell as, I am stuck at the step when Puppeteer is trying to launch chrome but evertytime it fails.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

please provide your target web app or anything to reproduce your problem!
